# Apache config with static file and proxypass on the same path

Tags: apache, static-files, proxypass

I have a requirement that I need to serve static files first, then proxypass on the same root path using Apache 2.4 config file (not .htaccess)

For example, with following files/folder structure

```
/index.html <-- static file
/favicon.icon <-- static file
/... <-- other static files etc
/img/image1.jpg <-- static file
/img/... <-- other static files etc
/service1 <-- proxy service
/service2 <-- proxy service
```

This seems to be easily doable through nginx, but I'm having a hard time to set this up on apache in config file since proxypass takes precedence and doesn't work when nested inside `<IF>, <Directory> or <Files>` tags.

Is this even possible with Apache? Any workarounds?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?